# Add 3 or 5 days to now, excluding weekends

Tags: vbscript, dateadd

I'm trying to get the future dates, 3 and 5 days from now. Excluding weekends.

**Example:** Today = 3/19/2013, 3 days = 3/24/2013, 5 days = 3/26/2013
The code below works for 5-7 days but I couldn't rework it for 3-5 business days.

```
dim strToday, businessDays5, businessDays7
strToday = date
select case WeekDay( strToday )
case 1     '-- Sunday
businessDays5 = 5 
businessDays7 = 9
case 2, 3, 4     '-- Monday - Wednesday
businessDays5 = 7
businessDays7 = 9
case 5, 6    '-- Thursday - Friday
businessDays5 = 7
businessDays7 = 11
case 7     '-- Saturday
businessDays5 = 6
businessDays7 = 10
end select
strFive = DateAdd( "d", businessDays5, strToday )
strSeven = DateAdd( "d", businessDays7, strToday )
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Working in classic asp, VBScript

Comment: so who got the answer right?

Answer (score 1):

I created one case for each day. It should give the results you want.

(EDIT: I changed the result so it's added to the current date, not to the first day of the week. Credit for that goes to @Goose who caught my mistake!)

```
dim strToday, businessDays3, businessDays5
strToday = date

select case WeekDay( strToday )

case 1     '-- Sunday
businessDays3 = 3
businessDays5 = 5

case 2     '-- Monday
businessDays3 = 3
businessDays5 = 7

case 3     '-- Tuesday
businessDays3 = 3
businessDays5 = 6

case 4     '-- Wednesday
businessDays3 = 5
businessDays5 = 5

case 5    '-- Thursday
businessDays3 = 4
businessDays5 = 5

case 6    '-- Friday
businessDays3 = 3
businessDays5 = 5

case 7     '-- Saturday
businessDays3 = 3
businessDays5 = 5

end select

strFive = DateAdd( "d", businessDays3, strToday )
strSeven = DateAdd( "d", businessDays5, strToday )
```

Comment: It's unfortunately displaying todays date for 3 days and 5 days as the same. 3/28/2014.

Comment: Today's Wednesday.  3 days from now is Saturday, so that gets converted to Monday.  5 days from now is Monday.  So they're both the same.  Did I understand that wrong?

Comment: it looks like the value you are assigning is the # of days to be added from day 1, not from today's date. So for today (Wednesday - 4), I believe it would actually be three = 5 and five = 7.

Comment: @Goose Oh! Right! I misinterpreted the original code. Thanks, Goose! I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Swagger Goose noticed that I misinterpreted your original code, so I fixed the numbers that get output. :)

Comment: @BrettFromLA You put me on the right path. This seems be working. 
Sun 3 & 6 
Mon 3 & 7 
Tue 3 & 7 
Wed 5 & 7 
Thu 5 & 7 
Fri 5 & 7 
Sat 4 & 6

Answer (score 1):

This universal function returns a date requested number of days from given date, skipping Saturadys and Sundays. See `Test()` below for example of how to call it.

```
Function AddDaysSkipWeekends(d As Date, days As Integer) As Date
    While days > 0
        If Weekday(d) > 1 And Weekday(d) < 7 Then 'Monday to Friday
            days = days - 1
        End If
        d = DateAdd("d", 1, d)
    End While
    Return d
End Function

Sub Test()
    MsgBox(AddDaysSkipWeekends(Today(), 3))
    MsgBox(AddDaysSkipWeekends(Today(), 5))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

using this function:

```
Function addDays_WithoutWeekend(Dateinput As Date, NumofDays As Integer) As Date
Do Until NumofDays = 0
Dateinput = Dateinput.AddDays(1)
If Dateinput.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday And Dateinput.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
NumofDays = NumofDays - 1
End If
Loop
Return Dateinput
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me after some editing.

```
dim strToday, businessDays3, businessDays5
strToday = date

select case WeekDay( strToday )

case 1     '-- Sunday
businessDays3 = 3
businessDays5 = 5

case 2     '-- Monday
businessDays3 = 3
businessDays5 = 7

case 3     '-- Tuesday
businessDays3 = 3
businessDays5 = 7

case 4     '-- Wednesday
businessDays3 = 5
businessDays5 = 7

case 5    '-- Thursday
businessDays3 = 5
businessDays5 = 7

case 6    '-- Friday
businessDays3 = 5
businessDays5 = 7

case 7     '-- Saturday
businessDays3 = 4
businessDays5 = 6

end select

strFive = DateAdd( "d", businessDays3, strToday )
strSeven = DateAdd( "d", businessDays5, strToday )
```

Comment: if need of businessDays2 or businessDays11 arises, you are at field 1 again and you can develop new constants. You solution is good at execution speed, not at human effort to put it together. Developers generally optimize first for human readability (their time is most expensive factor) and optimizations for speed/memory are done only in critical cases.